# What's the theme here?

Tags: visual, rebus

What's the theme, including individual rationales?

1.[image]
2.[image]
3.[image]
4.[image]
5.[image]
6.[image]
7.[image]
8.[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are all

> cartoon characters

1.

> Pigpen

2.

> Bugs Bunny

3.

> Tom and Jerry (Tom Brady and Jerry Rice)

4.

> Yosemite Sam (Yosemite National Park + Sam Elliott)

5.

> Spongebob Squarepants (@Pugmonkey) (not sure about this; they don't really look like sponges, and Billy Bob Thornton is a weird choice for "Bob".

6.

> Charlie Brown (Charlie Sheen)

7.

> Homer Simpson (Jessica Simpson hitting a "homer")

8.

> Popeye

Comment: How is number 3 Tom and Jerry?

Comment: @justhalf Those are their names.

Comment: "These are all..." I expected to read "really bad photoshops"

Answer (score 7):

5.

> SpongeBob Square Pants

Explanation:

> Billy Bob Thornton with rectangular (close enough to square) pants that seem to be made out of sponge